# Javascript/Jquery object.array.push()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in js programming and i have some problem. This example is trivialization of my problem. Here's function:

```
function sendOrder(){

    var someObject = {items:[]}; 

    $(document).ready(function(){               
        // pushing some item to array in object
        someObject.items.push({Name: "Orange", Quantity: 2, OrderUnit: "kg"});  
    });  

    // pushing second item to array in object
    someObject.items.push({Name: "Lemon", Quantity: 3, OrderUnit: "kg"});    

    console.log(JSON.stringify(someObject)); //print object
}
```

Result from console is:

```
{"items":[{"Name":"Lemon","Quantity":3,"OrderUnit":"kg"}]}
```

My question is: why Lemon is pushed to array in object and Orange is not?

Comment: Maybe Orange is pushed after the log was displayed.

Comment: the console.log() is being executed as soon as the JS is loaded, which means (likely) before the DOM has been loaded. $(document).ready() is available when the DOM has been loaded, so the log has been called before the ready function.

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys for comprehensive and quick answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `sendOrder` immediately from your `script` element, then it will execute before the DOM notifies that the document is ready. This is also when your `console.log` call is executed.

On the other hand, the function that you pass to `$(document).ready( ... )` will only be executed *later*, when the DOM notifies that the document has loaded. Then also that item will be added to your array, but this comes too late for being displayed by the `console.log` that was already executed.

Either move the `console.log` at the end of the callback function passed to `$(document).ready`, or move the `push` out of there, so that both `push` calls have happened before you display the result. In the first case the order will be opposite to what you might expect.

Answer (score 2):

`console.log` shows the actual state of the array, but since the `document` is not ready and the *Orange* object is not pushed yet, it shows up only the *Lemon* object.

You can e.g. add a `setTimeout` function with `1ms` delay to let the *console.log* wait until the page loads and both assigments are executed.

**Note**: The best option anyways would be just to get rid of that function, because it's just unnecessary.

```js
function sendOrder() {

  var someObject = {
    items: []
  };

  $(document).ready(function() {
    someObject.items.push({
      Name: "Orange",
      Quantity: 2,
      OrderUnit: "kg"
    }); //pushing some item to array in object
  });

  someObject.items.push({
    Name: "Lemon",
    Quantity: 3,
    OrderUnit: "kg"
  }); //pushing second item to array in object 

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(someObject); //print object
  }, 1);

}


sendOrder();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yea, sorry to hear it. When I left a comment the answer was incomplete. Screw all downvoters, you have +3 anyway and one from me. Cheerz!

Comment: @dfsq Huh, I hold no grudges anymore, it's all good. Cheers up!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the console.log is running before the Orange push command executes.  When you use $document.ready.function, it will wait until the entire page loads before executing the code in the function.  So your code outside of the document.ready.function will run BEFORE the code in the document.ready.function executes.

Answer (score 1):

The Orange is also in the array, the problem is that the console.log is executed before it was added. If you add an other console.log after the orange, you can see this.

```js
function sendOrder(){

var someObject = {items:[]}; 

$(document).ready(function(){               
    someObject.items.push({Name: "Orange", Quantity: 2, OrderUnit: "kg"});  //pushing some item to array in object
    console.log(JSON.stringify(someObject)); 
});  

someObject.items.push({Name: "Lemon", Quantity: 3, OrderUnit: "kg"});   //pushing second item to array in object 

console.log(JSON.stringify(someObject)); //print object
}

sendOrder();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `document.ready`'s callback is not called right away. It's called when the document is loaded, that after the log has happened. Here is an example of what is happening:

```js
var arr = [];

setTimeout(function() {
  arr.push("orange");   // will be pushed but after a second
}, 1000);

arr.push("apple");      // pushed right away (as a matter of fact pushed firstly because the above one is not evaluated so "orange" is not yet pushed

console.log("First Log: ", arr); // logged right away (before "orange" is pushed)

// Wait 2 second then log the array again
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("Delayed Log: ", arr); // enough time has passed (both "apple" and "orange" are pushed)
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the document.ready function, better to wait until your page is in a stable state before you code anyway. Instead, move the console.log INTO the document.ready, by which point you'll see both objects.

```js
function sendOrder(){

var someObject = {items:[]}; 

$(document).ready(function(){               
    someObject.items.push({Name: "Orange", Quantity: 2, OrderUnit: "kg"});  //pushing some item to array in object
    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(someObject)); //print object
});  

someObject.items.push({Name: "Lemon", Quantity: 3, OrderUnit: "kg"});   //pushing second item to array in object 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

this

```
$(document).ready(function() {...})
```

is just setting a function to be executed once the document is ready, It doesn't execute right away. You can use a similar form to respond to clicks on elements, like this:

```
$("#some-element").click(function() {...})
```

and you should only expect to execute when the event happens.